# Highcharts events broken: Type Error Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts 6 in Node 8, Angular 6, with the highcharts-angular wrapper, and am using a dynamically defined declarative setup.

Charts are rendered like this in template:

```
<highcharts-chart *ngFor="let chart of chartUtilities.charts; let i = index"
    [Highcharts]="chartUtilities.Highcharts"
    [constructorType]="'chart'"
    [options]="chartUtilities.charts[i].hcOptions"
    [callbackFunction]="chartUtilities.charts[i].hcCallback"
    [(update)]="chartUtilities.updateTrend"
    class="chart"
    id="trendChart{{i}}"
></highcharts-chart>
```

chartUtilities is a service that contains the declarative template, and functions that dynamically update the declared objects at runtime.

When the charting is updated, the driving code in the component copies the template, n-times, which results in n-charts getting rendered.  The component then calls the service function to draw the series and update options.

```
    //Create new charts based on the template
    let new_charts = [];
    for (let _i=0; _i<=num_items-1; _i++) {
      let this_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.chartUtilities.chartTemplate));
      new_charts.push(this_copy);
    }
    this.chartUtilities.charts = new_charts;
    this.chartSelected(builds data arrays, then calls service function to update template options and assign data arrays)
```

Mostly, this all works great.  I can use dynamic themes as an observable too, which is sweet.

The only part I can't figure out, is how to get events and custom functions working properly.  Currently, when I assign an events callback, like a custom button to fullscreen, I get an error at runtime when clicked, ie:

```
exporting: { buttons: { customButton: { text: null, symbol: 'square', onclick: this.toggleFullScreenTrend } } },
```

Runtime error:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
at SVGGElement.__zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYclick (highcharts.js:75)
at SVGGElement.wrapFn (zone.js:1332)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
at SVGGElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1770)
```

Other function handle assignments like formatters and callbacks are also broken.  It doesn't matter if I assign a function inline, or as a member, same result.

The only hint I have is that if I statically define each or any charts ahead of time, the function handle assignments work correctly, but this is undesired of course, since dynamic!

Any ideas on how to fix?  Really close to having a very sweet dynamic setup if I can get past this.

Here is a codesandbox that reproduces the issue:  http://codesandbox.io/s/angular-mv59c

I was expecting dynamically assigned functions in declarative creation to work correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like codesandbox? You can use this demo as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4. Try to simplify the app to show only this issue.

Comment: Yep, realized I need to do this too, will do

Comment: Here is a codesandbox that reproduces the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-mv59c

If you F12, and then press the box-icon added into the template, you'll see the error.

Comment: Something is wrong with your logic, after `this.chartUtilities.drawDynamicChart` inside chart options, there is no `exporting.buttons.customButton.onclick` function. I have set them manually and it works fine. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-qz891. This is not a Highcharts issue.

Comment: I see.  Did not realize I needed to assign the reference to each copy explicitly, thank you for the assist!